# pandas long-form table to nested json

Tags: python, json, pandas

I've been through the `to_json` and `json.dumps` documentation and tried different kinds of indexes and dicts, and I'm getting lost... I can create dict-like name-value pairs, but not the type of nested json I need.

I'm starting with a pandas dataframe in this format:

```
  level_1 level_2 level_3  numeric
0   alpha     one       a        1
1   alpha     one       b        2
2   alpha     two       a        3
3   alpha     two       b        4
4    beta     one       a        5
5    beta     one       b        6
6    beta     two       a        7
7    beta     two       b        8
```

And I need a JSON file with the following format:

```
{"alpha": {"one": {"a": 1, "b": 1}, "two": {"a": 3, "b": 4 etc...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a simple minimal example working on the data provided.

It could be enhanced by using only Pandas dataframe and also with a dynamic handling of the number of columns.

```
import pandas as pd
import json

# Declare the nested dictionary that will hold the result
class NestedDict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        self[key] = NestedDict()
        return self[key]

# Creation of the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({\
'level_1':['alpha' ,'alpha' ,'alpha' ,'alpha' ,'beta' ,'beta' ,'beta' ,'beta'],\
'level_2':['one' ,'one' ,'two' ,'two' ,'one' ,'one' ,'two' ,'two'],\
'level_3':['a' ,'b' ,'a' ,'b' ,'a' ,'b' ,'a' ,'b'],\
'numeric':[1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,5 ,6 ,7 ,8]})

# Creation of a multi-index
rr  = df.set_index(['level_1', 'level_2', 'level_3'])

d = NestedDict()
# Loop to store all elements of the dataframe in 
# the instance of NestedDict
for k in rr.iterrows():
    d[k[0][0]][k[0][1]][k[0][2]] = k[1].values[0]
# JSON output
json.dumps(d,default=str)
```

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to get back to you, it works perfectly. It took me a few minutes to parse that loop! (I mean for my mind to parse it, my computer did it really fast.)